How to render Iterating an object in html in react js
My Dashboard component is a arrow function as shown below
const Dashboard= (props) => { 


//users object is fetched

    return(

        <ul>
            {
                Object.keys(users).forEach((key,index) => {
                    console.log("iterating------>"+users[index].name);//this is iterating
                    return  <li key={key}>hello</li>//this is not rendering
                })
            }
            
        </ul>
    )



}

This way it is not rendering to html. Please help
Tried my best but didn't get the expected output

You are using forEach inside the JSX which does not return anything. In React to render a list you should use map instead that way it returns a new array that React can render as JSX elements.
You can use this example instead
const Dashboard = ({ users }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(users).map((key) => (
                <li key={key}>{users[key].name}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};


Use map instead of forEach and it should work
Here's the corrected code:
const Dashboard = (props) => { 
//users object is fetched

return (
    <ul>
        {
            Object.keys(users).map((key, index) => {
                console.log("iterating------>" + users[key].name); // Log each user
                return <li key={key}>hello {users[key].name}</li>; // Render <li> for each user
            })
        }
    </ul>
);
}

Or use this (I prefer and use):
const Dashboard = (props) => { 
//users object is fetched

return (
    <ul>
        {
            Object.keys(users).map((key, index) => (
               
                 <li key={key}>hello {users[key].name}</li>; // Render <li> for each user
            ))
        }
    </ul>
);
}

Hope this helps...

<ul>{Object.values(users).map(({id, name, ...restUserProps}) => (<li key={id}>{name}</li>))}</ul>

